# Reputation gained from editing lost and not added back

Tags: support, reputation

Today I edited two questions. One was deleted by the OP so after I briefly gained +2, I lost it, for apparent reason. This is fine.

So at this moment I was at 193 +2 -2 = 193.

I then edited this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207052/behaviour-of-is-not-and-python) and got approved as well. That got me another +2, which however didn't get added to my reputation again.

Here I would expect my rep goes up to 195 again.

Could anyone explain to me if this is correct or is it a bug?

The below shows the +2 added for editing the question mentioned above.

[image]

And my reputation tab:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked your reputation tab?

Comment: That's not your reputation tab. That's your reputation graph.

Comment: @yivi that shows me the same thing as well, or are you referring to different thing?

Comment: Your reputation tab: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4436572/stucash?tab=reputation

Comment: @yivi thanks. just updated it. does that look normal ?

Comment: @yivi have read the guide, thanks. but I still can't see why and how. basically I was on 193 for days and first edit today got me to 195; then back to 193. unless there's someone unapproved an edit (which isn't listed in the guide, even if it is there, I should be able to see an record in today that someone unapproved something.)

Comment: Most likely, some other post that you edited was deleted as well. Try to save your suggested edits for **good** posts.

Comment: @yivi I'll take that as an answer, because that's the only way I could see to lose another 2 points silently. thanks.